# CouchDB - an outer join on a many to many relationship

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have couchDB database with 3 sets of documents
Items, Users, Reviews
A many to many relationship is maintained in Reviews document for Items and Users

User

```
{"type":"user","user_id":"U1"},
{"type":"user","user_id":"U2"},
{"type":"user","user_id":"U3"}
```

Item

```
{"type":"item","item_id":"I1"},
{"type":"item","item_id":"I2"},
{"type":"item","item_id":"I3"},
{"type":"item","item_id":"I4"}
```

Review

```
{"type":"review","item_id":"I1","user_id":"U1","score":4},
{"type":"review","item_id":"I1","user_id":"U2","score":3},
{"type":"review","item_id":"I2","user_id":"U1","score":4},
{"type":"review","item_id":"I3","user_id":"U3","score":1}
```

I want to get an outer join on Items and Users using reviews so as to get the below results

Intended Result

```
{"total_rows":16,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"...","key":"I1","value":["item"]},
{"id":"...","key":"I1","value":["review","U1",4]},
{"id":"...","key":"I1","value":["review","U2",3]},
{"id":"...","key":"I1","value":["review","U3",0]},
{"id":"...","key":"I2","value":["item"]},
{"id":"...","key":"I2","value":["review","U1",4]},
{"id":"...","key":"I2","value":["review","U2",0]},
{"id":"...","key":"I2","value":["review","U3",0]},
{"id":"...","key":"I3","value":["item"]},
{"id":"...","key":"I3","value":["review","U1",0]},
{"id":"...","key":"I3","value":["review","U2",0]},
{"id":"...","key":"I3","value":["review","U3",1]},
{"id":"...","key":"I4","value":["item"]},
{"id":"...","key":"I4","value":["review","U1",0]},
{"id":"...","key":"I4","value":["review","U2",0]},
{"id":"...","key":"I4","value":["review","U3",0]}
]}
```

I am using the tips mentioned in here
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EntityRelationship#Many_to_Many:_Relationship_documents

```
"many_join_review": {
           "map": "function(doc) { 
                   if (doc.type == 'review') { 
                        emit(doc.item_id,[doc.type,doc.user_id,doc.score]); 
                    } else if (doc.type == 'item') { 
                        emit(doc.item_id,[doc.type]); 
                    }"
  }
```

I am getting the below result instead

```
{"total_rows":8,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a0056fc","key":"I1","value":["item"]},
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a006bc8","key":"I1","value":["review","U1",4]},
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a006be0","key":"I1","value":["review","U2",3]},
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a005eb0","key":"I2","value":["item"]},
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a0075cf","key":"I2","value":["review","U1",4]},
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a006409","key":"I3","value":["item"]},
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a008313","key":"I3","value":["review","U3",1]},
{"id":"d5e26b9da1683232d1c208241a0065d7","key":"I4","value":["item"]}
]}
```

So what should I change to have the intended result as in how to get 0 as score on items whose reviews don't exist for a user. Do I need to add something under reduce section.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like OLAP cube.

Comment: What is "zeros in items"?

Comment: Can you display what output you *do* get?

Comment: Zeros in items - as in having score as 0 for the items which has not been reviewed by a user. Like in SQL in a left outer join we get null on records which doesn't exist for the foreign key constraint. I have updated the post with the result I am getting. Thanks